# Capturing Information in a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I want to use a function in JavaScript to capture the information from the form in an 
object so that i can store that object in the localStorage.

But when i use the form tag the function does not seems to be called.

do i need to change something in the form or remove the form tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Test form and localstorage</title>
      <script>
         function submit(){
            var client = {
            Name: document.forms['contact']['name'].value,
            Age: document.forms['contact']['age'].value,
            Sex: document.forms['contact']['sex'].value
            }
            console.log(client);
            localStorage.setItem('client',JSON.stringify(client));
                           }
      </script>
      </head>
<body>
    <form name = "contact" method = "post" action="#" onsubmit = "submit()">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class = "blockSize" id = "td1">Name:</td>
                <td class = "blockSize" id = "td2"><input type = "text" name = "name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class = "blockSize" id = "td3">Age:</td>
                <td class = "blockSize" id = "td4"><input type = "text" name = "age"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class = "blockSize" id = "td5">Sex:</td>
                <td class = "blockSize" id = "td6"><input type = "text" name = "sex"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

I need it to be in JavaScript only, so any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you sure it is not getting called. Have you turned on `Preserve log upon navigation` on your console (if using chrome)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the issue you're having is that you didn't prevent the default behavior of the onsubmit event. Try adding `return false` to the end of your `submit` function.

If you don't do that, the form will try to `POST` the information to the page it's currently on, which will refresh the page and remove the user's data. If you want to capture that data, you will need to use something other than Javascript.